# ENS name reverse is not working on Ethereum address

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I'm trying to both resolve and lookup using "ethjs-ens" the lookup call is working correctly. However, the `resolve` call is throwing an empty error.

The address I'm using on the `reverse` function is the one I got from calling `lookup`, I'm also logging a validation to check that both addresses are the same `console.log("is the same", address === result);`

```
import ENS from "ethjs-ens";

//assume metamask installed
//testing on main network
const ens = new ENS({ provider: window.web3.currentProvider, network: 1 });

const address = "0x96619cd92fe0c7deaaee1c8043a7fea79cfa3e71";
const name = "example.eth";
const fn = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await ens.lookup(name);
    console.log("adddress", result);
    console.log("is the same", address === result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("lookup", e);
  }

  try {
    const resultName = await ens.reverse(address);
    console.log("name is", resultName);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("name", e);
  }
};
fn();
```

[Code live sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-brook-rsmir)

`reverse` is always failing not sure what could be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wanting to get the reverse lookup and was running into issues with `ethjs-ens` as well as `ethereum-ens` packages.  Ended up going with `ethers`. This worked for me:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);
const name = await provider.lookupAddress(address);
```